# Emulator Like Galaxy S3 in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can i Create AVD Like Samsung Galaxy S3.Can Someone gives the Hint for tools and Tutorial.
Thanks

I want Skin Like Galaxy S3.

With this Answer i have got An Error

Starting emulator for AVD 's3'
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I Have Also Change the resolution 720*1028 manually so this problem is solved.

Comment: What do you mean by `AVD like`? Do you mean the appearance or something else? Please state your question correctly.

Comment: AVD means Android Virtual Device Like the samsung Galaxy Phone

Comment: Do you have ICS downloaded and installed?